# MySQL MariaDB wont create Table with a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, mariadb

I'm having a problem with my SQL Tables. So I have my Usertable:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NICKNAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NICKNAME`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ;
```

This table already exists and was created without any problems. I Want to create a score Table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NICKNAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `HIGHSCORE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (NICKNAME) REFERENCES USER(Nickname)
)
```

On execution of the query I get this errormassage:

```
**#1005 - Kann Tabelle `xxxxx`.`scores` nicht erzeugen (Fehler: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)**
```

Its in German and says cant create Table, Error 150, I cant see where the key constraint is wrong, I used the same syntax in postgreSQL and it worked fine, but somehow MySQL is not accepting it. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is strange.  If `nickname` is indeed the primary key, then your code should work.

It is much more nature, though, to use the auto-incremented column as the primary key.  If you want the nickname, then use a join when you query.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserId int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NICKNAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `HIGHSCORE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES USER(Id)
);
```

Comment: So If I create User again with the following query it should work?:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NICKNAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NICKNAME`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `NICKNAME` (`NICKNAME`)
)

Comment: @AraLight . . . Your original code should work, with `nickname` as the primary key.  But I would change the users table so the integer column is the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

user - is a keyword.

It may be a good idea to use another table name e.g. "tblUser",
or use quotes again ``

```
FOREIGN KEY (NICKNAME) REFERENCES `USER`(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr. Gordon Linoff I was able to find my Mistake:

I had to declare NICKNAME to be declared UNIQUE, only then the FOREIGN KEY constraint could be added to other tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NICKNAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NICKNAME`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `NICKNAME` (`NICKNAME`)
);
```

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY`; you have added an unnecessary index.